# open cart language and currency

Tags: php, module, currency, opencart

Can anyone answer me regarding how I relate currency with language in open cart? I mean that

if I change language the currency regarding to that country also changes. I searched in all place but I didn't find. Can any one has such experience?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to combine the two on the front-end?   e.g. customers only have to select contry and it auto selects currency?

Comment: Exactly you are right that I wanted .

Comment: What version of OpenCart?    You essentially need to edit the controller to change both at once... If you only deal with a couple currencies, you could just hard code the pairs.. If not, you would also need to create a language-to-currency composite table...    Let me know what version of OC, as well as how many languages you use

Comment: Open cart version is 1.5.1 and the site url is inksupplydepot.com/xmasdeco/  which is on testing . there are five languages.

Answer (score 2):

you need to modify the controller/common/header.php

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($this->request->post['language_code'])) {
        $this->session->data['language'] = $this->request->post['language_code'];

        if (isset($this->request->post['redirect'])) {
            $this->redirect($this->request->post['redirect']);
        } else {
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home'));
        }
    }
```

for something like that:

```
    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($this->request->post['language_code'])) {
     $this->session->data['language'] = $this->request->post['language_code'];
     $this->currency->set($this->request->post['currency_code']); 
     unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']); 
     unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']); 
     if (isset($this->request->post['redirect'])) {
        $this->redirect($this->request->post['redirect']);
     } else {
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home'));
     }
   }
```

I know that's answer is inside StackOverflow but i don't found it again.

and now.. you need to modify the template header.tpl :

```
   <form name="language" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div id="language">
        <img src="image/flags/se.png" alt="Svenska" title="Svenska" onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'se'); $('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', 'SEK'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" />
        <img src="image/flags/dk.png" alt="Danish" title="Danish" onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'da').submit(); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" />
        <img src="image/flags/gb.png" alt="English" title="English" onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'en').submit(); $('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', 'GBP').submit(); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" />
        <input type="hidden" name="language_code" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" />
     </div>
  </form>
```

Best Regards,

Comment: I had to make changes to latest OC 1.5.6 but why the: unset line?

Comment: Here are also a part of the solution made to language.tpl http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=50047